# Can't find example file in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn glmnet (http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) but can't find the example RData files from the tutorial.  I get

```
> library(glmnet)
> load("MNExample.RData")
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection In addition
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
cannot open compressed file 'MNExample.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I then tried going to the R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3. directory, and used find, the file wasn't there.

Any ideas on where it could be?  Or is that not how tutorials work?

Comment: This is a strange tutorial -- it looks like they've referenced their own local `.RData` files.  They certainly aren't in the package so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In the [glmnet descriptive pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf), there is "examples" sections after each described function. I don't know if there is a way to get it directly in R but you can copy-paste these examples from the pdf to R, it works.